# How to set query timeout when using Presto CLI?

Tags: presto

I am using the presto cli from a bash script to extract some simple data to a csv. I am trying to use the --client-request-timeout parameter and set it to 5s (it says the default is 2m). My query takes ~1 minute, however I do not get a timeout error (I am trying to see what the error says so I can handle it in the bash script to notify query failure).

I have tried toggling --client-request-timeout from 1-10 seconds but cannot get the query to timeout, and it is taking up to a minute to return.

```
sudo /folder/to/presto-cli --server server:8080 --catalog catalog --user user --schema some_customer --client-request-timeout 5s --execute "select val1, val2, sum(count) from table where processed=false group by val1, val2;"
```

I am expecting the presto-cli to give me an error that I can then handle in my bash script.

Comment: --client-request-timeout  specifies the request communication timeout. You could hit that timeout in case of Presto service unavailability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set query time limit using `query_max_execution_time` session property.

```
SET SESSION query_max_execution_time = '30s';
```

You can get the list of supported session properties with `SHOW SESSION` query (or [looking at the source code](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/b3acfe7da770d960fa3e83bbdaba74629c58ae81/presto-main/src/main/java/io/prestosql/SystemSessionProperties.java#L66)).

With `presto-cli`, use `--session` arg to pass this:

```
presto-cli --session query_max_execution_time=30s ...
```

Example

```
$ presto-cli --session query_max_execution_time=15s \
    --execute "select count(distinct regexp_extract(comment, '([a-zA-Z ]+)+$')) from tpch.tiny.lineitem"

Query failed: Query exceeded the maximum execution time limit of 15.00s
```